# Build an array in AHK from mouse clicks

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking to build an array of mouse click coordinates. I'm struggling to understand how you build out a two-dimensional array. Or if I'm going about this wrong and should build two arrays. One with X-coordinates and one with Y-coordinates.

I can easily build out an array with just X coordinates or just Y-coordinates. Can I somehow build out X and Y into the same 2-D array?

```
ArrayX := []
ArrayY := []
counter:=1

^Lbutton::
  MouseGetPos CurX, CurY
  ArrayX[counter] := CurX
  ArrayY[counter] := CurY
  counter++
return

^q::
  loop % ArrayX.MaxIndex()
    items.= ArrayX[A_Index] "," 
  StringLeft, items, items, Strlen(items)-1
  Clipboard := items
  msgbox % items
  items:=""  
  
  loop % ArrayY.MaxIndex()
    items.= ArrayY[A_Index] "," 
  StringLeft, items, items, Strlen(items)-1
  Clipboard := items
  msgbox % items
exitapp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd create a multidimensional or a jagged array in AHK by just assigning the element at the desired index an array.
`Array[3] := [481, 529]`
And you'd access it by just accessing the elements in order, e.g:
`Array[3][2]` would result in 529.

Other things to improve on your script:

1. You might want to use the [`.Push()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Push) method to append values to your array.
2. A [for loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm) might be a desirable alternative to normal looping and worrying about the index:
   `for each, element in Array`
3. [`StringLeft`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringLeft.htm) is a deprecated legacy command and shouldn't be used anyone. [`SubStr()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SubStr.htm) replaces it.
   However, for what you were doing with it, [`RTrim()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Trim.htm) would be better/easier:
   `RTrim(items, ",")`

Revised script:

```
Array := []

^LButton::
  MouseGetPos, CurX, CurY
  Array.Push([CurX, CurY])
return

^q::
    For each, element in Array
        items .= element[1] ", " element[2] "`n"
    MsgBox, % RTrim(items, "`n")
    ExitApp
return
```